# Directory at path content filtering

Tags: cocoa, filter, directory, filtering, nsfilemanager

is there possibility to retrive from NSFileManager paths without paths specified in some kind of filters without if's ? I know that there is a method includingPropertiesForKeys, but it can have only predefined keys, i would like to use custom ones...

Dose anybody encouter similar issus ?

Any sugestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to filter using NSFileManager is to do it yourself as you described (loop the contents, examine the properties, add matches to a "matches" array). The ...includingPropertiesForKeys:... part isn't a filter, it just pre-fetches the desired properties so you don't have to fetch them for each returned file path.

Or you could use a Spotlight query.

Comment: Ha, we meet again :)
"The only way to filter using NSFileManager (...)" so do You propose another way ?

Comment: That was a "cover my a**" tactic as I think a Spotlight query may help you.

Comment: Mate... You did it again, that's the thing i was looking for, thx.

Comment: There. Edited my questions so that I was right *all along*! ;-)